# C# connecting to database and safe entry of data

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a few questions about connection to MySql database in c#.

I made a connection to database based on this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IH0dYO8QOow but i readed in comments bellow video that this kind of approach is vunearable to MySql injection.

I'm working in PHP with PDO prepared statements in MySql, now i want to know:

- is it better to make a server on localhost with xampp, wamp .... or install Microfost Sql server
- how to make query-s with prepared statements in c# and how to make it safe

I'm using Microsoft Sql server 2014 for creating database.

And please don't give me a negative scores because i'm new in c# and want to learn and i heard this is best place to ask a question and get proper help.

Here is code of simple login form that connect to database and checking for valid username and password, if all is good it opens new window and hide a login form.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // connect to a database
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mario\Documents\mojaBaza1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

            // make new query
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '" + textBox1.Text + "' AND password = '" + maskedTextBox1.Text + "'",connection);

            // fetch data from table
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            sda.Fill(dt);

            // check query for result, if returned 1 login
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                // hides new window
                this.Hide();

                // instance of new window when user log in
                Main ss = new Main();

                // show new window
                ss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                // error message if user entered invalid data
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password, please try again.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is vulnerable to SQL injection as you are using direct inputs from text boxes. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Do you mean you're using SQL Server Management Studio to set up your MySQL database?

Comment: `"I'm working in PHP with PDO prepared statements in MySql"` - The syntax is different, but the concept is the same.  *Never* directly concatenate user input into SQL code.  Use parameters instead.  This doesn't change between different programming languages.  What PHP may call "prepared statements" C# may instead call "parameterized queries".

Comment: @DangerZone yes, but as i saw on video i don't need managment studio because i can create database and tables direct  throught VS.

Comment: @MarioLukacic while you can create tables and databases in code, generally it's easier and better to do it with SSMS, that way you don't pollute your code with something that will only ever run one time, and the check to see that it doesn't need to run again, including the query that has to fail to ensure that. See my answer for your original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mario\Documents\mojaBaza1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
SqlCommand cmd= connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=@username AND password=@password";
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@username",textBox1.Text);
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@password",maskedTextBox1.Text);
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

This way you use parameters for your query, which is pretty much the C# version of a prepared statement.

Comment: I tried your code and i get error on "connection" variable http://prntscr.com/ebabfi, and don't u need to define parameters before query itself or it's how this is c# is handle it ?

Comment: @Mario `cmd.parameters.AddWithValue()` is how you define parameters, The order of the three lines defining the CommandText and the parameters is interchangable.  My code was ment to replace just where you defined your dataAdapter you still need `SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mario\Documents\mojaBaza1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");` before it

Comment: Thank u @Andrew, but that don't works all time i'm getting same error. I'm reinstalling VS and Server maybe it's problem in them.

Comment: @Mario Try this, I changed the code, it should get around your issue, for some reason it looks like your code is trying to use the wrong overload for the SqlCommand constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew very much, i suppose problem was in my VS 2017, i installed now VS 2015 + Microsoft SQL Server 2014 ExpressAndTools + mysql-connector-net-6.9.9 and all works fine. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySql Wamp.

```
private void checkuserifexist()
{
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=databasename");
con.Open();
try
{
MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM login where ID='" + txtid.Text + "'";
MySqlDataReader exist = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(exist.HasRows)
{
login();
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("This user doesn't Exist", "ID not exist", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}

//login code
private void login()
{
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=databasename");
con.Open();
String strusername = txtusername.Text;
String strpassword = txtpassword.Text;

string sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username='" + strusername + "'AND Password='" + strpassword + "'";
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
da.Fill(ds);

for(int i = 0; dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
if(dt.Rows[i]["Userlevel"].Equals("Administrator"))
{
this.Hide();
Admin admin = new Admin();
admin.ShowDialog();
}
}
}
```